# Checking if the entered date is the start of a quarter

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, validation, momentjs

Good afternoon! Can you please tell me how to implement a function that checks if the passed date is the beginning of the quarter?
I tried to implement validation using the moment.js library and created a function

```
const isStartOfQuarter = (date: string) => {
  return moment(date).isSame(moment().quarter(moment(date).quarter()).startOf('quarter'), 'day')
}
```

When calling this function with the date "2022-04-01" it returns true and works correctly, but if you try to call it with the date "2023-04-01" it does not work correctly and returns false

I also need to make a function that checks if the passed date is the end of the quarter
I created a function for this

```
const isEndOfQuarter = (date: string) => {
  return moment(date).isSame(moment().quarter(moment(date).quarter()).endOf('quarter'), 'day')
}
```

When calling this function with the date "2022-06-30" it returns true and works correctly, but if you try to call it with the date "2023-06-30" it does not work correctly and returns false

Can you please tell me how to implement this functionality correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest using momentjs. Even the authors [recommend using alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for new developments.

In this case it is quite easy to do with native JavaScript, as there aren't that many quarters after all:

```js
const isStartOfQuarter = (date) =>
    ["01-01", "04-01", "07-01", "10-01"].includes(date.slice(5, 10)); 

const isEndOfQuarter = (date) =>
    ["03-31", "06-30", "09-30", "12-31"].includes(date.slice(5, 10)); 

console.log(isStartOfQuarter("2023-04-01"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really more convenient to use native js

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the built-in `Date` type.

```
const isStartOfQuarter = (dateStr) => { 
  const d = new Date(dateStr); 
  return d.getUTCDate()==1 && d.getUTCMonth()%3==0
}

const isEndOfQuarter = (dateStr) => { 
  let d = new Date(dateStr); 
  d.setDate(d.getDate()+1); 
  return isStartOfQuarter(d);
}
```

Which work as advertised in Node:

```
> isStartOfQuarter("2023-04-01")
true
> isEndOfQuarter("2023-06-30")
true
```